# Can i reference a user/group inside SharePoint if our admin hide them from the AD global address list

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, active-directory, administration, people-picker

Our system admin wants to hide some users/groups from the AD global address list to prevent those users from showing when sending emails through outlook. so my question is if we can still reference (add inside SharePoint group + assign the user inside a people/group column) users/groups inside SharePoint online sites, if our admin hide them from the AD global address list?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, SharePoint isn't dependent on the Exchange Global Address List, rather it uses Azure AD as it's point of reference for user/group objects.

Answer (score 1):

I've done the test.

We can still reference users/groups inside sharepoint online sites, if we hide them from the AD global address list.